# Make typescript interfaces in a sibling directory globally available

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, apollo-client

My directory is structured as shown:

```
src/
├── global.d.ts
├── index.ts
├── pages
│   └── page01.ts
└── types
    ├── Type01.ts
    ├── Type02.ts
    └── Type03.ts
```

Using [apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling) I am able to generate types / interfaces for my queries with the following command:

`apollo client:codegen --target=typescript --outputFlat src/types`

The interfaces are then generated in my **types** directory.

If I want to use any of these generated types in **page01.ts** an import is required. eg: `import { TypeName } from '../types/Type01.ts'`.

Is there are way to globally include all the types in this directory (perhaps in **global.d.ts**) so that an import is no longer required?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't do that.  You should use `import`s.